# porque obtengo un 'NAN' al realizar esta operación matemática con jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

estoy construyendo un formulario con 3 inputs en los cuales el usuario digita unos valores y calcula el resultado con una formula pero nose que estoy haciendo mal ya que genera un nan

este es el código

```
<script>
            var r = $('#r').val();
            var g = $('#g').val();
            var p = $('#p').val();

            var IPGJO = (r + g)/p*100;
            
            $('#check').on('click', function(){
                $('#IPGJO').text(IPGJO);
            });
        </script>
```

este es uno de los input que estoy utilizando

```
<div class="input-group mb-3">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="r">
    <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon2">Remates</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Por cierto, donde quieres traer el resultado? en un cuarto input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema radica en que cuando presionas click no estás leyendo los valores que tienen tus inputs. Cuando la página se carga, se carga con los inputs vacíos, por tanto los valores iniciales de tus inputs serán nulos. Para cuando llamas a la función `$('#check').on('click',...)` las variables `r`,`p` y `g` tienen los valores nulos de cuando se cargó la página, nunca más los volviste a leer, de ahí el error que te da. Haces las operaciones con cosas que no son númeos (**NaN** - ***N**ot **a** **N**umber*).

**Solución**: mueve la obtención de los valores de los inputs al interior de la función.

Te adjunto un ejemplo:

```js
$('#check').on('click', function(){
    let r = $('#r').val();
    let g = $('#g').val();
    let p = $('#p').val();

    let IPGJO = (r + g)/p*100;
    $('#IPGJO').text(IPGJO);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div><input type="number" id="r"></div>
<div><input type="number" id="g"></div>
<div><input type="number" id="p"></div>
<div><button id="check">Check</button></div>

<br>
<div>Resultado: <span id="IPGJO" ><span></div>
```

Comment: Brooo!, Como no me di cuenta! Llevo como media hora revisando el por que no le funcionaba el código JAJajAJjAj, claaro, no se me ocurrió meter todo en una función xd, que crack, ojala esta respuesta le funcione...

Comment: si, efectivamente, xD hoy aprendí algo nuevo de jquery, gracias we

Answer (score 0):

fijate que estas llamando mal a las variables

```
mal -> var IPGJO = (r + g)/p*100;
bien->  var IPGJO = (remates + goles)/pases*100;
```

Recordá que las variables ya las tenes definidas arriba, con sus respectivos nombres, ya no debes volver a utilizar el nombre del campo donde se encuentran como #g por ejemplo.

Prueba en consola:

```
var remates = 10;
var goles = 5;
var pases = 1;

var IPGJO = (remates + goles)/pases*100;
alert(IPGJO);
```

Alerta con valor 1500.

Espero tengas un gran día.

EDIT: Por cierto, el NaN significa "Not a Number" osea No es un Número, ya que literalmente estabas intentando subar y dividir letras o en su defecto variables no declaradas.

Comment: hola, gracias por su amable ayuda, he hecho lo que me comenta pero aun sigo obteniendo el NAN por otro lado al hacer un concole.log(r) no veo ningún valor que podría ser?

Comment: Disculpa no habia visto la parte de arriba, pero obviamente el problema radicaba en lo que te dije, pero por lo que veo tenes ademas otro problema... llama al input de la siguiente manera...
var remates = document.getElementById("r").value;

Comment: @KatiaSisHost es obvio que es una mala práctica llamar a tus variables con nombres que no tienen ningún sentido ni representan nada, pero eso nunca va a darte un error de compilación ni de ejecución. Tu respuesta no resuelve el problema ni se acerca a su causa.

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez el post fue editado, 1 de los problemas es el que le mencioné, sino no lo hubiese dicho... el ahora cambió en el post principal y coinciden con la explicación que le dí... antes estaba llamando  var IPGJO = (r + g)/p*100; .. pero R G y P no estaban definidas en ningún lado.. (ahora en el post principal si porque lo modificó).